# Оформление причастных оборотов

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли оформлен причастный оборот?

Таким образом, благодаря новому конструктивному решению, величина усилий, возникающая при деформации седельных поверхностей диска и отверстия, не влияет интенсивно на процесс износа, приводящий к ухудшению герметичности.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые расставлены верно, а вот с согласованием тут проблемка.
Я так понимаю, что к ухудшению герметичности приводит процесс износа, так? В таком случае правильно будет написать не "приводящий к ухудшению", а "не влияет на процесс износа (кого, что?), приводящего к ухудшению герметичности".

Comment: Это если согласовать с износом. А тут согласуется с процессом. "Процесс, приводящий к ухудшению..."

Comment: Процесс износа и износ - фактически одно и то же, семантику  выражения определяет слово "износ", к тому же оборот стоит ближе к этому слову (формальное согласование).

Answer (score 1):

Да, согласование надо исправить:

Таким образом, благодаря новому конструктивному решению, величина усилий, возникающих при деформации седельных поверхностей диска и отверстия, не влияет интенсивно (=не оказывает интенсивного влияния) на процесс износа, приводящего к ухудшению герметичности.